# PowerBI Get cumulative value for each day and reset value each year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, cumulative-sum

I want to achive do cumulate values per day per product and reset the value for every new year.

What I have:

| Date | productID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | 1270 | 30000 |
| 01.01.2022 | 1280 | 200000 |
| 02.01.2022 | 1280 | -50 |
| 01.02.2022 | 1280 | 100 |
| 01.02.2022 | 1280 | 200 |
| 01.02.2022 | 1270 | -20 |
| 01.03.2022 | 1270 | 80 |
| 29.12.2022 | 1270 | 100 |
| 29.12.2022 | 1280 | 10 |
| 31.12.2022 | 1270 | 35 |
| 31.12.2022 | 1270 | 5 |
| 01.01.2023 | 1270 | 50000 |
| 01.01.2023 | 1280 | 100000 |
| 04.01.2023 | 1270 | 50 |
| 06.01.2023 | 1280 | -100 |

Value should be calculated cumulative per day with a fresh start from each year and per productID.

What I want as a measure is Cumulative Per Year.

| Date | productID | value | Cumulative per Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2022 | 1270 | 30000 | 30000 |
| 01.01.2022 | 1280 | 200000 | 200000 |
| 02.01.2022 | 1280 | -50 | 199950 |
| 01.02.2022 | 1280 | 100 | 200050 |
| 01.02.2022 | 1280 | 200 | 200250 |
| 01.02.2022 | 1270 | -20 | 29980 |
| 01.03.2022 | 1270 | 80 | 30060 |
| 29.12.2022 | 1270 | 100 | 30160 |
| 29.12.2022 | 1280 | 10 | 200260 |
| 31.12.2022 | 1270 | 35 | 30195 |
| 31.12.2022 | 1270 | 5 | 30200 |
| 01.01.2023 | 1270 | 50000 | 50000 |
| 01.01.2023 | 1280 | 100000 | 100000 |
| 04.01.2023 | 1270 | 50 | 50050 |
| 06.01.2023 | 1280 | -100 | 99900 |

What I tried:

```
Cumulative per Year =
VAR varProductID = SELECTEDVALUE(MyTable[productID])
VAR varYear = SELECTEDVALUE(MyTable[date])

CALCULATE(SUM(MyTable[Value],

    FILTER(MyTable,
varProductID = MyTable[productID] &&
varYear = MyTable[date]

    )

What I also tried is STARTOFYEAR() and ENDOFYEAR() to know when the cumulative should reset but I not meant to work with selectedvalue() also for some reason MyTable[date].Year wont work.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work...

```
   Cumulative per Year =
VAR _date =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR _id =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[productID] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[value] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            _id = 'Table'[productID]
                && 'Table'[Date].[Year] = YEAR ( _date )
                && 'Table'[Date] <= _date
        )
    )
```

Comment: @Schwenk i made a little revision on the code after testing ...

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is TOTALYTD time intelligence measure and drop it in as a last column and see if it works.
It would look something like this:

```
Cummulative Total=TOTALYTD(SUM(Table[Value]),DateTable[Date])
```

If you don't have it already you will need to create a date dimension table, see link here for a steps on how to create a Calendar table > https://radacad.com/all-in-one-script-to-create-calendar-table-or-date-dimension-using-dax-in-power-bi
Create a relationship between calendar table date > your table date and then use cummulative total measure. Always best to have date dimension table.